# Renci SSH.Net Concurrent SFTP Upload Performance

Tags: c#, sftp, ssh.net

I’ve been working with the Renci SSH.Net library for SFTP uploads and I’ve run into some interesting behavior when uploading the same file to two different servers concurrently, using two separate threads.

When I load the file to a single server I get transfer speeds ~1500KB/s which is about what I expect given the server.

When I transfer the same file to two servers concurrently I get transfer speeds ~650KB/s to each server.

This is all on a local GbE network, and I know the NIC on the PC is capable of at least 7MB/s so that’s not the bottleneck.  It also doesn’t appear to be CPU bound either as it barely registers on the processor.

A few things I’ve tried already:

- Creating a FileStream for each client that references the same file.
- Reading the file into a byte array and creating a MemoryStream for each client.

Is there some sort of threading contention issue with this library?

Comment: Do you get better results using any other SFTP library or a standalone SFTP client?

Comment: I tested with WinSCP and found much better performance than even a single SSH.Net connection.  I updated to the latest NuGet release and everything was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue with the latest NuGet release (2016.1.0)  Performance was drastically improved.